# How to implement progressive response from Servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, http, servlets

New to stackoverflow so i am sorry if i broke any formatting rules.
I have implemented in Java some fully functional algorithms about the calculation of topK best results utilizing RTrees and IRTrees. This calculation is also progressive, which means that when a response is calculated it is automatically displayed.

However, what i have currently achieved from my website creation is to discard the progressive capability of my algorithms and instead provide the answers to the user when they are ready from my servlet. To the client i utilize AJAX with JQuery to handle the call to the servlet.

What i want to know is how i can utilize a connection so as to send responses to the client whenever an answer is calculated. I have read about html5 sse but i don't think it's appropriate to my case. What do you think? What resources and advice can you give me?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I managed to find a solution to my problem. WebSockets inspired me and i stumbled upon a framework called Atmosphere that looks like it can suit my needs. Thank you!

Comment: you have to use websocket. http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/25/websockets-using-modern-html5-technology-for-true-server-push/

Comment: WebSocket is one option. Another one could be to use AsyncContext introduced in Java EE 6.

Comment: @Adi thank you for the comment. I have read about websockets(unfortunately i've not used them before), but is there a fallback in case a browser doesn't support WebSockets?  Also, i'am currently reading about AsyncContext and it seems like a good idea